# Generic programming in Haskell with SYB and ad-hoc polymorphism

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

I have a class identical to [Show](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aShow) and I would like to make an instance of this class for each tuple type. Usually this is done by writing separately instances for each tuple type

```hs
instance  (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b)  where
  showsPrec _ (a,b) s = show_tuple [shows a, shows b] s

instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (a, b, c) where
  showsPrec _ (a,b,c) s = show_tuple [shows a, shows b, shows c] s

instance (Show a, Show b, Show c, Show d) => Show (a, b, c, d) where
  showsPrec _ (a,b,c,d) s = show_tuple [shows a, shows b, shows c, shows d] s
...
```

Writing one instance per tuple type results in a lot of boilerplate and it's easy to see the common pattern shared among all the `showPrec` implementations. To avoid this kind of boilerplate I thought I could use [Data.Generics](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/syb-0.1.0.2/Data-Generics.html) from [Scrap your boilerplate](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/hmap/index.htm) and implement a folding over tuples, like

```
showTuple = intercalate " " . gmapQ ("" `mkQ` show)
```

But `showTuple` doesn't work for some reason

```
> showTuple (1,2)
" "
```

I think the problem is the fact that `show` is polymorphic because if I specialize `showTuple` then it works

```
showTupleInt = intercalate " " . gmapQ ("" `mkQ` (show :: Int -> String))
```

```
> showTupleInt (1::Int,2::Int)
"1 2"
```

I have checked the code of [gshow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.4.1/docs/Data-Generics-Text.html) that does something similar to what I need, but I can't figure out how it works. If I try to import its code into GHCI I get an error:

```
> let gshows = (\t -> showChar '('
                      . (showString . showConstr . toConstr $ t)
                      . (foldr (.) id . gmapQ ((showChar ' ' .) . gshows) $ t)
                      . showChar ')'
                      ) `extQ` (shows :: String -> ShowS)
<interactive>:262:59:
Could not deduce (a ~ d)
from the context (Data a)
  bound by the inferred type of
           gshows :: Data a => a -> String -> String
  at <interactive>:(259,5)-(264,44)
or from (Data d)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
             Data d => d -> String -> String
  at <interactive>:262:33-65
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the inferred type of gshows :: Data a => a -> String -> String
      at <interactive>:259:5
  `d' is a rigid type variable bound by
      a type expected by the context: Data d => d -> String -> String
      at <interactive>:262:33
Expected type: d -> String -> String
  Actual type: a -> String -> String
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `gshows'
In the first argument of `gmapQ', namely
  `((showChar ' ' .) . gshows)'
In the second argument of `(.)', namely
  `gmapQ ((showChar ' ' .) . gshows)'
```

So I have two questions:

1. what's wrong with `showTuple` and how can I fix it such that it will work with tuples of any size
2. how `gshow` works and why if I import its code on GHCI I get that error?

**EDIT:** I'm studying `Data.Generics` and in general SYM, so I would like to use that module. I will accept an answer only if it uses just that module. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You're right that `showTuple` doesn't work because of the polymorphism of `show`. The problem is that `mkQ` wants to pick out one specific type:

```
mkQ :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => r -> (b -> r) -> a -> r
```

The `b` in the type signature has to be one specific type for each use of `mkQ` - without the type signature the defaulting rules are probably picking something (not sure what!), whereas with the type signature it picks `Int`.

Your `showTupleInt` does work on tuples of any *size*, but of course not on tuples of any *type*.

The problem with defining `gshows` in GHCi is that it really needs a type signature to be able to type check, because of the recursive use of `gshows` in its own definition at a different type to the original invocation. Without the type signature the type-checker wants the definition of `gshows` to have exactly the same instantiation of the type variable as the use of `gshows` - which shows up as the `Could not deduce (a ~ d)` type error.

You can see this by putting it in a source file with and without the type signature - with the signature it typechecks fine, without it you get a similar error to the one you got, if you first use `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`.

`gshows` works at all because of the type of `gmapQ`:

```
gmapQ :: Data a => (forall d. Data d => d -> u) -> a -> [u]
```

In contrast to `mkQ`, the parameter it takes is itself polymorphic - note the nested `forall`.

Although your `showTuple` also uses `gmapQ`, it's too late - `mkQ` has already caused the trouble by forcing `show` to only work on one type.

You also can't use `show` directly with `gmapQ` directly because the constraints are different - `gmapQ` wants something that will work on any instance of `Data`, whereas `show` is constrained by `Show`. `gshows` never actually uses the `Show` type class generically, although it does use `shows` specialised to `String`.

It's difficult to prove a negative in a case like this, but I'm fairly sure that you can't write anything like `showTuple` that will use the `Show` class polymorphically using just `syb`, because it simply doesn't have anything that can "recognise" types that have a particular instance. That's why `syb-with-class` exists.

Also, if you really do want something that just works on a single level of the type structure, i.e. shows any size tuple but uses something else for the elements of the tuple, then `syb` is arguably the wrong solution because it is designed for operating recursively and finding things at *any* level of a data structure. My view is that the `GHC.Generics` solution is the nicest one for implementing `showTuple`.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, thank you! Ok, not I understand why it is not working. What I don't understand from your answer is if it is possible to implement `showTuple` even by changing the code completely (remove `gmapQ` maybe?) but by using `Data.Generics`. If you can provide or explain why is not possible I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm more familiar with GHC Generics, rather than with SYB, so I'm offering a solution based on Generics. While it doesn't directly answer your question, I hope it could be also useful.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts, DefaultSignatures #-}
import Data.Sequence
import GHC.Generics

class Strs' f where
    strings' :: f a -> Seq String

instance Strs' U1 where
    strings' U1 = empty

instance Show c => Strs' (K1 i c) where
    strings' (K1 a) = singleton $ show a

instance (Strs' a) => Strs' (M1 i c a) where
    strings' (M1 a) = strings' a

instance (Strs' f, Strs' g) => Strs' (f :*: g) where
    strings' (a :*: b) = strings' a >< strings' b

class Strs a where
    strings :: a -> Seq String
    default strings :: (Generic a, Strs' (Rep a)) => a -> Seq String
    strings = strings' . from

-- Since tuples have Generic instances, they're automatically derived using
-- the above default.
instance Strs () where
instance (Show a, Show b) => Strs (a, b) where
instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Strs (a, b, c) where
```

Comment: I like your implementation using `GHC.Generics` but I can't accept it because it uses another module. I would like to use `Data.Generics`.

Comment: @mariop No problem, I just wanted to chip in my 2¢. Hopefully somebody else more fluent with SYB will provide the full answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [syb-with-class](http://code.haskell.org/package/syb-with-class).
It predates `-XConstraintKinds`, so you need to write an instance of a `Sat`
class and derive the Data class that this library derives. Here is an example,
that's pretty close to the showTuple example, except I add some {}:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, TemplateHaskell, UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Generics.SYB.WithClass.Basics
import Data.Generics.SYB.WithClass.Instances
import Data.Generics.SYB.WithClass.Derive

data A a b c = A a b c deriving Show
data B a = B a deriving Show
data C a = C a deriving Show

derive [''A,''B,''C]

data ShowD a = ShowD { showD :: a -> String -> String }
instance (Show a) => Sat (ShowD a) where
    dict = ShowD shows

gshow x = case gfoldl ctx 
                (\ (s, f) x -> (s . ("{"++) . showD dict x . ("}"++) , f x))
                (\y -> (id ,y))
                x
        of (str,_) -> str ""
    where
        ctx :: Proxy ShowD
        ctx = undefined

x1 = A (B 'b') (C "abc") (B ())

{-
>>> gshow x1
"{B 'b'}{C \"abc\"}{B ()}"

>>> show x1
"A (B 'b') (C \"abc\") (B ())"
-}
```

The second argument to `gfoldl` gets to call `shows (B 'b')`, `shows (C "abc")`
and `shows (B ())` thanks to the `showD dict` which gets the `shows` function
with the correct type.

Comment: Thanks @aavogt, your proposal is very interesting. I don't accept it only because it requires another module. I would like to avoit using another module on top of SYM just for this. If you have a solution using only `Data.Generics` then I will be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @mariop, I think the best you can do with SYB is to list out types that you know have `Show` instances at one point. For example `mkQ "" (show :: Integer -> String) \`extQ\` (show :: Int -> String) \`extQ\` (show :: Double -> String) :: GenericQ String` can be supplied to `gmapQl` to show those three types. That's pretty limited, since there are many possible types you might forget (`[[[[(Int,Double,String)]]]]` has a `Show` instance) or be unable to list (since they not defined yet). But maybe `extQ` is good enough for you.